# How to remove duplicate values in autocomplete?

Tags: angular, typescript

I use "ng-select". How can I remove duplicate values ​​from autocomplete? That is, I’ll assume two times in the `group_operations` field added the `SPB` value, then how can I remove the `SPB` value from the drop-down list for auto-completion from the auto-complete list that was added a second time or more.

```
<ng-select [addTag]="true" formControlName="group_operations" id="group_operations">
  <ng-option *ngFor="let sprOperation of sprOperations" [value]="sprOperation.group_operations">{{sprOperation.group_operations}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: you can create a unique pipe for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method :

```
function uniques(array: any[], key: string) {
  return array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc.find(item => item[key] === curr[key])) { acc.push(curr); }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Either in a pipe, the array prototype, or your component.

Snippet :

```js
function uniques(array, key) {
  return array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc.find(item => item[key] === curr[key])) { acc.push(curr); }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(uniques([
  { id: 1, value: '1' },
  { id: 1, value: '1' },
  { id: 2, value: '2' },
  { id: 3, value: '3' },
], 'id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the sample code that can be modified according to your data-set.

```
export class DataComponent {

  constructor() {
    items: any[];

    // Get all sprOperations
    const operation = items.map(sprOperations=> sprOperations.group_operations);

    // Unique sprOperations
    this.sprOperations= operation.filter((x, i, a) => x && a.indexOf(x) === i);
  }
}
```